# Flash - Is there a way to get a list of instance variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-cs6

Either in flash pro or flash builder is there a way to get a full list of instance variables? I have an existing FLA with several hundred objects on the stage with instance names. It would be useful if I could get a list of the existing instance names to which I'm going to be adding more interactivity.

EDIT: I'm going to be using this for further development in Flash Builder on the existing FLA that was created in Flash Pro.

Comment: You can profile the runtime to view current and lifetime instantiations.

Comment: Another possibility to throw in the mix is again like wvxw said, depends on use, but you can also write a JSFL script against the main document / Classes to print a list in any fashion you want using regex to format it.

Comment: I'm going to be using this for further development in Flash Builder on the existing FLA that was created in Flash Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can trace out stuff using describeType. add this on your maintimeline to test.

```
import flash.utils.describeType;
var a1:String = 'oi';
var b1:Array = [1,2,3];
var c1:int = 123;
trace(describeType(this));
```

loop thru the xml to find variables (there's loads more things there)
[...]

```
<extendsClass type="Object"/>
<implementsInterface type="flash.events::IEventDispatcher"/>
<implementsInterface type="flash.display::IBitmapDrawable"/>
<variable name="a1" type="String"/>
<variable name="b1" type="Array"/>
<variable name="c1" type="int"/>
<accessor name="enabled" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
```

Comment: You can also use `avmplus.describeTypeJSON` , which is a lot faster